# My Object is null but I can still call functions on it (== null returns true) (getType returns myType)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a List of objects and want to delete buttons that reference a specific object in that list if the object gets removed. My problem is that when I add an Object to that list the buttons immediatly delete themselves once the object gets added because it supposedly is null.

Every button has a component with the Objects 'name' property (ProductName) and I look for an Object in the list with the same name, if it finds one (which it does) it shouldn't return null (but it does).

What am I missing here?

Here is the Update method (attached to the buttons) in question,

```
    private void Update()
    {
        Product p = GameManager.Instance.shoppingCart.Find(n => n.pname.Equals(gameObject.GetComponentInParent<ProductName>().name));
        Debug.Log(p);
        Debug.Log("p is of type " + p.GetType());
        Debug.Log("p is null is " + (p == null));

        if (p == null)
        {
            Object.Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        if (ButtonIsClicked)
        {
            GameManager.Instance.AddProduct(p);
            ButtonIsClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Product class

```
public class Product : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string pname;
    public int quantity;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float price; // the price of the product times the quantity
    public float basePrice; // The price of a single unit

    override
    public string ToString()
    {
        CalcPrice();
        return pname + ": " + price + "€" + "   x" + quantity + "\n";
    }

    public void CalcPrice()
    {
        price = basePrice * quantity;
    }
}
```

And here is the Update function that spawns the buttons

```
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = amount; i < GameManager.Instance.shoppingCart.Count; amount++, i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(ButtonPrefab, transform.position + new Vector3(200, Ypos, 3), Quaternion.identity);
            go.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("PopupPanel").transform;
            ProductName pname = go.AddComponent<ProductName>();
            pname.name = GameManager.Instance.shoppingCart.ElementAt(amount).pname;
            Ypos -= 30;
        }
    }
```

The Debug Logs return (in order):

Debug Product: 1€   x1         //according to Products toString() function

p is of type Product

p is null is True

Comment: `Product` derives from `MonoBehaviour`, which overrides the `==` operator with some strange concept of equality to `null`. https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/

Comment: How do I check for null then?

Comment: You can use `ReferenceEquals(p, null)`. Or if C# 7.0 is available, you can do `p is null`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try those out Edit: That did it thank you!

Comment: One more way you can do it: `(object)p == null`. Casting to `object` "erases" the type information so that the overloaded operator no longer applies.

Comment: For MonoBehaviour (and other `Object`s) you can simply use `if (!p)` see [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)